# How to set environment variable in databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, environment-variables, databricks

Simple question, but I can't find a simple guide on how to set the environment variable in Databricks. Also, is it important to set the environment variable on both the driver and executors (and would you do this via spark.conf)? Thanks

Answer (score 27):

**Before creation:**

You can set environment variable while creating the cluster.

Click on **Advanced Options** => Enter **Environment Variables**.

[image]

**After creation:**

Select your **cluster** => click on **Edit** => **Advance Options** => Edit or Enter new  **Environment Variables** => **Confirm and Restart**.

[image]

**OR**

You can achieve the desired results by appending my environment variable declarations to the file /databricks/spark/conf/spark-env.sh. You may change the init file as follows:

```
%scala
dbutils.fs.put("dbfs:/databricks/init/set_spark_params.sh","""
  |#!/bin/bash
  |
  |cat << 'EOF' > /databricks/driver/conf/00-custom-spark-driver-defaults.conf
  |[driver] {
  |  "spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode" = "DYNAMIC"
  |}
  |EOF
  """.stripMargin, true)
```

For more details, refer “[Databricks – Spark Configuration](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/clusters/spark-config.html)”.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As an aside: these variables can be accessed via `os.getenv("myenvname")` . Commenting here because this info was amazingly difficult to find.

Comment: Can we save file in .env file and load the variables in another file

Answer (score 2):

Use databricks cluster policy [configuration](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/clusters/policies.html#cluster-policy-attribute-paths).
The configuration will auto-add the environment variables during policy selection.

```
spark_env_vars.MY_ENV_VAR: {
  "value":"2.11.2",
  "type": "fixed"
}
```